# How can I attach add rel="lightbox" to a specific link?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, menu, hyperlink, rel

I'm building a site in wordpress and need to add a lightbox to a specific link in the menu. I've tried several methods, but can't seem to get them to work. I'm certain it's just a mixup in the way I'm going about it.

In any event, [here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aFLLB/) to show my latest attempt.
    `$("a[href$=login.asp").attr("rel", "lightbox")`

Thanks!

Comment: You haven't select to use JQuery in your fiddle BTW, so that isn't going to work anyway

Comment: Oh right. He he. I've updated it and still no dice.

Comment: I have posted an answer, but I didn't realise you wanted it to show dice too... I will have to make a change

Comment: [Here is the update with the dice](http://jsfiddle.net/aFLLB/10/), as per your request. Glad to help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple of things wrong:

1) You are not closing your attribute selector brackets (as suggested already)

2) Your href value contains a full stop, because of this you need to wrap the value in quotes too

This is what you want:

```
$("a[href$='login.asp']").attr("rel", "lightbox")
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/aFLLB/5/)

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `]` in your jQuery selector. Try `$("a[href$=login.asp]").attr("rel", "lightbox")`

Answer (score 0):

Try this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aFLLB/9/

Added braces and quotes to

```
href$='login.asp' aswell
```